# Is the Annabelle doll in Annabelle, the same one from Annabelle: Creation?

Tags: the-conjuring-universe, annabelle, annabelle-creation

In the 2014 movie **Annabelle**, the protagonist Mia Form receives an Annabelle doll as a gift from her husband. In its 2017 *prequel* **Annabelle: Creation**, we can see a doll-maker making the very first Annabelle doll. He marks it as the **1st of 100 limited edition dolls**.

[image]

Annabelle: Creation is set in year **1955** and its sequel is set in **1967** (12 years later). Mia mentions that she has been looking for one of those dolls.

> *INT. NURSERY - MOMENTS LATER*
> Some people choose animals as a theme. Others choose the moon and stars. Mia clearly chose --
> DOLLS.
> Of all sorts. Like she's been collecting them for awhile. On the rocking chair. On the shelves.  In the crib.

> *SECONDS LATER*
> Mia tears at the wrapping, revealing --
> Those eyes. Those pig tails. That smile. We know her as the ANNABELLE DOLL. But we've never seen her like this.
> New. Perfect. Exquisite.
> **Mia** : Oh my god... John...
> **John** : That's the one, right?
> **Mia** : Yes. Where did you find her? I mean, do you know how long I've been looking?
> **John** : I know.

[[Script]](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/annabelle-2014.pdf)

Is it the same one that gets possessed by the demon in Annabelle: Creation?
Note that

> Annabelle Higgins (who's actually Janice from Annabelle: Creation) is later found dead with her arms around the doll, which implies there's some sort of connection between her and this doll.

Answer (score 2):

### It apparently is the same doll.

As your question suggests, the *Annabelle* films aren't entirely clear on this point. However -- in [an interview with iHorror's David Grove](https://www.ihorror.com/interview-screenwriter-gary-dauberman-annabelle-creation/) -- the screenwriter of *Annabelle* (2014) and *Annabelle: Creation* (2017), Gary Dauberman, appears to confirm that the doll in the latter film is indeed the same one seen in the former, and the other [Conjuring Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring_Universe) films.

> DG: How was the decision made to do a prequel to Annabelle, and how did you come up with a storyline for this second film?
>
> GD:  It was a true collaborative effort between me and the producers. James [Wan] had a very specific idea on the location and a few of the characters he thought would be fun to play around with when making the second movie. As usual, he was right. And **we all knew we wanted to dig into the origin of the Annabelle doll. It just felt like a natural way into the story. Where’d she come from? Who made her? How did the evil that’s attached to her come to be? Once we had those answers, I started to hammer out a basic structure we could all look at. And then from there I set out writing the script. It all came together pretty quickly.**
>
> [...]
>
> DG: Do you see any room for more Annabelle films, another Annabelle prequel or maybe a sequel, and what is the connection between your upcoming film The Nun and the Annabelle films?
>
> GD: I think this movie will prove by the end of it that there is more to the Annabelle story that needs to be told. I mean, the mere fact that she’s a doll kind of allows that. **How many kids out there have the same doll? Visually, I mean. Same packaging, same hair, same eyes, same whatever. But it’s unique to them, right? Same doll but each kid creates a different back-story, a different history, a different story which makes their doll their very own even though it might look like a million others out there. It’s kind of the opposite for Annabelle. She remains the same but the people she encounters all have different stories and different fears** and she’s going to use those for her own purposes until you discover — much too late — that she isn’t the toy… you are. And she’s playing you.
>
> <sub>[Interview] Screenwriter Gary Dauberman – Annabelle: Creation</sub>